# Deploy of subgraph fails in Amazon EC2 Instance

Tags: blockchain, database, docker, the-graph, query

I want to run [`graph-node`](https://github.com/graphprotocol/graph-node) (The Graph) in an Amazon EC2 Instance.

I have setup everything with `docker-compose` and the 3 containers (`graph-node`, `ipfs` and `postgres`) are running smoothly.

I have also setup my own version of a subgraph, based on the Open Zeppelin's implementation (`@openzeppelin/subgraphs`).

The problem arises when I want to deploy the subgraph by running the following command:

`graph deploy --ipfs http://localhost:5001 --node http://localhost:8020 generated/sample ./generated/sample.subgraph.yaml`

I am getting:

`*** stack smashing detected ***: terminated Aborted (core dumped)`

My EC2 Instance has 8 vCPUs and 32 GiB RAM. This is double what I have on my localhost and where it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem I was having was related to using the `sudo` command to run:

- `docker`
- `docker-compose`
- `npm`

What I did to avoid this was:

1. Create a new user `graph` to avoid having permission errors when trying to install `npm` packages globally
2. Add `graph` user to newly created `docker` group to avoid using `sudo` to run both `docker` and `docker-compose` (refer to method 3 of [this link](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/docker-permission-denied))

After doing this, the error disappeared (I was probably accessing prohibited areas of the stack by abusing of the `sudo` command).